# The problem of widget isn't invoked using google assistant

Tags: app-actions

Do anyone have the similar problem to control Android apps (from google codelab - fitness app) with their voice, using Google Assistant?

In my app, I tried to activate widget using google assistant (app action tool test), but google assistant doesn't give any respond. Therefore, I used the example code google gave to run, but it still has similar problem that widget isn't invoked when I use app action tool test to test the app.

Sample code google provided:
https://github.com/actions-on-google/appactions-fitness-kotlin.git

the shortcut looks like below and how :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FArmK.png)

Update:

After updating the new running record, the app won't respond when I want to trigger widget after the first time I can do it successfully. Do anyone have similar question or know how to solve it?

[App updates running record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FArmK.png)

The widget cannot update/display the new running record

[widget cannot be trigger to get new running record](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y07uq.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as a screenshot. On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) and [*Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Comment: The more information you can provide, the better our chances are of being able to help you. Updating your question to include a link to the codelab you're trying to do, the step that you're on, what you've tried to do to test it, what you expected, and what it did instead can provide information for us to help.

Comment: The updates are important. Have you attached adb to see what is being invoked and if the app is getting called again? Are you seeing any toast messages when you try to invoke the widget a second time?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you're talking about the codelab titled [Integrate Android Widgets with Google Assistant](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/appactions-widgets#0).

I've been able to get this codelab to work - mostly.

When testing using the App Actions test tool:

- Make sure you have uploaded the app to a project in the Google Play Console. You'll only need to do this once, even if you change your code.
- Make sure the account you're using for Android Studio, Play Console, and Google Assistant on your device are all the same.
- Make sure you've compiled the app and deployed it to your device. The easiest way to do this just to run it from Android Studio the first time.

  [image: Run widget on Android Studio]
- When you create the preview, set the name and Locale.

  - Even tho these are listed as "optional", these make it easier to debug.
  - The App name should be something you know will be recognized by voice and not used by any other app. I tend to use things like "Splat" and "Bogus".
  - Set the locale to en-US
  - Click "Create Preview"

  [image: Picture of App Actions Test Tool]
- Once the preview is created, you can test the widget running by

  1. Setting the Intent to `GET_EXERCISE_OBSERVATION`
  2. Changing the value in the "name" property to something like `"run"`. ("Climbing" will also work, but tell you that you don't have that activity logged.)
  3. Making sure the target device is the one you're testing on.
  4. Clicking Run App Action

  And you should see the widget appear in the Assistant on the device.

  [image: Test Tool and Emulator]

You don't need to use the test tool, however. Once you have created the preview with the Test Tool, you can just test it right on the device:

1. Start the Assistant by long-pressing on the home button.
2. Saying or typing a request such as "How far have I run with Bogus" ("Bogus" being the name I've chosen this time

[image: Emulator]

If you have issues with the emulator, there are some other [troubleshooting](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/troubleshoot) steps which may be useful depending on the error message you get.

Now, I did say "mostly". I have seen issues where it will stop responding at all, either via the Test Tool or directly via the Assistant. A few things that I've done that often (but not always) help:

- Delete and then create the preview again.
  Remember that the Preview is only available for a few hours.
- Force stop the application.
- Force stop the Google Assistant.
- Even if you don't see a message, check out the Troubleshooting steps for ["Sorry, I couldn't find that"](https://developer.android.com/guide/app-actions/troubleshoot?authuser=2#test_5)

Comment: hello, thank you for your answer. I did what you said already, but there is a problem still bothers me is that sometimes (many times) the app won't respond when you want to trigger the widget after the first time everything is perfect. I am not sure whether you have the same issue or not.

Comment: That is similar to the problems I'm running into as well. If I force shutdown the app, it works again, but otherwise it seems hit or miss about how many times I can invoke the widget and get a response.

Comment: (I've added some additional steps in the answer.)

Comment: perfect and if your widget will not show any response try "Hey google how many miles I have run on <app-name-define-in-action-tool> app"
also, make sure you install the app first and then update/create a preview

Comment: @Prisoner I am trying to trigger custom intent from the assistant and get a response from the app in the app widget but every time I trigger this from the voice command it won't work, do you have any sample code for custom intent with a widget.?

Comment: Aside from the codelab code - I do not. You may wish to start a new question and show the code you're trying to use and clearly explain what you've tried and what doesn't seem to be working.